# Python type hint - can assign string to List[int]?

Tags: python

I tried the following code and there is no error. Why `l` can have a string in the list?

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from typing import List
>>> l :List[int] = [ 'abc' ]
>>> l
['abc']
```

Comment: Python type hints are meant to be checked by a static analyzer like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), they have no effect at runtime. If you run mypy over that it will rightly complain.

Comment: Type hints are *hints* to people reading source code. Now, third-party libraries like `mypy` or `pytype` may do static analysis, or others like `pydantic` may do runtime type checking, but python is a dynamically typed language and type hints don't change that